# How should I declare my class to deserialize the following JSON object?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm getting the following as JSON response:

```
string responJsonText = 
{
  "QuestionMasterData":
  [
    {"question":"First Name"},
    {"question":"Second Name"},
    {"question":"Last Name"},
    {"question":"Password Field"},
    {"question":"Re type password"},
    {"question":"Email"},
    {"question":"Phone"},
    {"question":"Address"},
    {"question":"State Zip"},
    {"question":"Country"},
    {"question":" Lorem Ipsum as their default model text. Many desktop publishing"}
  ],
  "status":1
}
```

I want to deserialize it to .NET object. 
For this I am trying something like this:

```
QuestionResponseClass response = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestionResponseClass >(responJsonText);
```

And I designed the QuestionResponseClass class as follows

```
public class QuestionResponse
{
    public List<string> listQs { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}
```

Clearly, I am making some mistake while declaring the class. Can anyone tell me what should be the type?

Comment: Try using http://json2csharp.com/ to generate model for your desired JSON

Comment: Thanks :) It worked. I wasted my entire day on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object does not match the json:

1. `listQs` should be called `QuestionMasterData` or use the matching attribute for specifying field name.
2. `QuestionMasterData` contains a list of objects with one property of `question` and is not a `List<string>`.
3. `status1` should be called `status`.

Something along:

```
public class QuestionResponse
{
    public List<Question> QuestionMasterData { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string question { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `status1` should be `status`.